# wifi doesn't work on asus X555LD

Tags: wireless, asus, 16.04

I've just installed ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop, but my wireless card doesn't work. What can i do to fix it?

```
lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network 

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [11ad:6675]
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 255
Region 0: Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

I've installed this from terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and after reboot i disabled the secure boot.